# How to create a sub-organization in Liferay 6.1

Tags: liferay-6, liferay-aui

I want to create a sub-organization inside a Organization in Liferay 6.1.

Please guide me to achieve this.

Regards,
Dinesh.

Comment: do you want to create it using coding or using control panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create sub organization you can use this code snippet

```
OrganizationLocalServiceUtil.addOrganization (
                userId, parentOrganizationId, name,
                type, recursable, regionId, countryId,
                statusId, comments, false, serviceContext);
```

**Note :-** Pass **parentOrganizationId** to link sub organization to parent oraganization

HTH